# LWP::UserAgent and login credentials

Tags: perl, credentials, lwp, lwp-useragent

I'm trying to set up the credentials with LWP::UserAgent, but I'm not able to log in. `$username`, `$passwd` are correct. I don't understand what should I put in `3rd argument`(according to dos `$realm`, here `Authentication`). Here the snippet:

```
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.5) Gecko/20060719 Firefox/31.2.0',
$browser->credentials("domain.com:80", "Authentication",$username, $passwd);
my $response=$browser->get("http://domain.com/page");

print $response->content;
```

Comment: Does the `Realm` match the one the server is asking for? If you do `credentials($username,$passwd);` does it work then?

Comment: @Sobrique This is my problem... I said I don't know what I should put there... credentials($username,$passwd) doesn't work neither.

Comment: Close your browser and reopen it. Navigate to `http://domain.com/page`. If the site is using basic authentication, you should get a popup that says something like `A username and password are being requested by http://domain.com. The site says: "foo bar"`. In this case, `foo bar` is the realm.

Comment: If credentials without a realm don't work, they're the wrong credentials.

Comment: @user897237 What did you do to get it working? You should write that as an answer (not a comment) so future users with the same problem can see how you solved it.

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but I suggest you look at WWW::Mechanize.  It is a wrapper around LWP::UserAgent that makes common spidering tasks easier.  If your program is going to do anything with the page content like follow links or extract images, WWW::Mechanize will make things much easier with convenience methods like $mech->find_link() and $mech->follow_link().

Answer (score 4):

I corrected realm as @ThisSuitIsBlackNot suggested:

```
Close your browser and reopen it. Navigate to http://domain.com/page. 
If the site is using basic authentication, 
you should get a popup that says something like 
A username and password are being requested by 
http://domain.com. The site says: "foo bar". 
In this case, foo bar is the realm.
```

Then I was able to login, but the pages were empty. 
So I have  added a cookie:

```
$browser->cookie_jar({ file => ".mycookies.txt" });
```

Comment: No need to use a separate browser.  If you have LWP installed, you probably have scripts `GET` and `HEAD`. Do a `HEAD` against a protected resource, an you'll get a prompt `Enter username for **realm** at **host**:**port**: `.